# Conditional CSS - Only showing Box-Shadow if Background Colour is not Opaque

Tags: jquery, css

I've searched around for this quite a bit but haven't found anyone trying to solve this problem which I find weird. I'd preface this with me having 6 years+ of front end experience and I honestly don't know the best approach.

We have an app where Users create dynamic divs and they decide the size/color/shape off these divs. To stylise them a bit we have given the divs a box-shadow to make them look better. The problem comes in when a user decides to have a transparent background (we use rgba for bg-color and you have a slider that can make the opacity 0) and then the box shadow still remains and it does not look good. I've been trying to look at writing conditional CSS for this but don't think it is possible.

The only solution I can think off is having a class that has no box-shadow with important to overrule it, and with jQuery parse the bg-color and look for the Opacity value - if its 0 then add this class. This seems very clunky and like a bad approach, but maybe this problem is unique enough that this is the only solution? 
Interested in hearing peoples thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `box-shadow` width `drop-shadow`. The latter will show nothing for a transparent div:

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:5px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  filter:drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #000);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="background:red;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background:blue;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background:white;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background:rgba(0,100,0,0.5);"></div>
<div class="box" style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0);"></div>
```

Or like below if you want the drop-shadow to only be around borders:

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:5px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  position:relative;
}
.box::before,
.box::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:-1;
}
.box::before {
  background:inherit;
  filter:drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #000);
}
.box::after {
  background:#fff; /* this should be equal to main background */
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="background:red;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background:blue;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background:white;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background:rgba(0,100,0,0.5);"></div>
<div class="box" style="background:rgba(0,100,0,0.3);"></div>
<div class="box" style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0);"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/chille1987/9gd7ukqh/27/

If you use inline styles to control bg color than it could be done with some Jquery.

```
<div class="box" style="background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0);"></div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.box.no-shadow {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

JS

```
$('.box').each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var currentColor = $(this).css('background-color');
    var rgba = currentColor.match(/\d+/g);
    var counter = 0;

    for(var i in rgba) {
      counter++;
      var last = rgba[i];
    }

    if(counter === 4 && last == 0) {
        el.addClass('no-shadow');
    }
});
```